# How do I change an element (e.g. h1 -> h2) using jQuery / plain old javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Of course, there are a whole range of possible errors relating to document validity, but my immediate stumbling block occurs when changing a paragraph (`p`) into an `address` element. My current method is (more-or-less):

```
var p = $('p#test');
p.replaceWith('<address>' + p.html() + '</address>');
```

but that fails for this specific case; it works perfectly for p -> blockquote or h2 -> h3. Firebug suggests that a self-closing element (`<address/>`) has been added to the document, for some reason.

Can anyone spot the bug or suggest an alternative method?

Comment: This worked fine for me on a minimal page. Does your page validate?

Comment: It validates at load time, yes. As far as I'm reading the HTML spec correctly, it validates after the change too (i.e. an address can replace a p in any context).

Comment: just in case you wonder what's wrong: p.html() gets the html content of the first matched element. You'd have to use this approach using p.each(...);

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var p = $('p#test');
var a = $('<address>').
    append(p.contents());
p.replaceWith(a);
```

Your solution is subject to all sorts of horrible HTML escaping issues and possibly injection attacks.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for the answer, but doesn't that assume that an address element already exists? Imagine the body consists solely of "<p>stuff</p>" and I want it to be "<address>stuff</address>"

Comment: No, the syntax $('<address></address>') creates a new address element which can then be used to replace the p.

However do notice that I've just made a correction to my original post.

Comment: Wow - that's a new bit of jQuery on me :) Thanks, Daniel - works like a dream.

Answer (score 0):

You'll could use a placeholder around the title:

```
<span id="demo"><h1>Title</h1></span>
```

Then use JavaScript DOM to create new values for the innerHTML property.

```
<script type="javascript">

setTitle = function(id, tag, title) {
  var container = document.getElementById(id);
  container.innerHTML = '<' + tag + '>' + title + '</' + tag + '>';
}

setTitle('demo', 'h1', 'My Title');

</script>
```

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? It's unhelpful to downvote something like this without explaining why...

Comment: Do it owerwrite whole <placeholder> or simply overwrite the target <tag> with new string?

Comment: It's downvoted because: 1) It doesn't answer the question. The question asked how to replace an existing tag with another tag but preserving the contents of the original tag. This code replaces the tag and its contents. 2) It requires an extra placeholder tag for no good reason. 3) It doesn't escape `tag` or `title`, so those variables could contain HTML tags which would be parsed and injected into the page. This could be the vector for an injection attack. Basically, this answer is a fractal of badness.