# Jquery - How do I change the parent of an element from an H1 to a P?

Tags: jquery

Jquery - How do I change the parent of an element from an H1 to a P?

I have `<h1>heading</h1>`, how do I change it to `<p>heading</p>`

I think I could `$.unwrap` then `$.wrap`, but is there a better way?

Comment: $.unwrap then $.wrap sounds good to me.

Comment: If you do $('h1').unwrap().wrap('<p/>') - you will actually remove the parent of h1 and replace it with p, ending up with <p><h1>heading</h1></p>. What if the parent of h1 is body? ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('h1').wrapInner('<p/>').children().unwrap();
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is pretty close (I would consider it a duplicate) of [How do I change an element (e.g. h1 -> h2) using jQuery / plain old javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240467/how-do-i-change-an-element-e-g-h1-h2-using-jquery-plain-old-javascript)

Using this solution, your answer would resemble

```
var p = $('h4');
var a = $('<p/>').
    append(p.contents());
p.replaceWith(a);
```

Test it here: http://jsbin.com/abaja/edit

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new element with the contents of the H1, then hide the H1.

```
var contents = $('h1').html();
$('h1').after('<p>'+content+'<p>');
$('h1').hide();
```

Comment: Instead of hide() which leave it there, why not remove()?

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<h1 id="a">heading</h1>
```

jQuery:

```
var $a = $('#a');
var contents = $a.contents();
$a.remove();
$('body').append('<p>' + contents + '</p>');
```

`$.unwrap` would remove the parent of the matched element. In other words, if `#a` were the child of a `div`, the `div` would be removed and not the `h1`.

Comment: This script however does not replace (as in change it in-place), it appends to the end of body.

Comment: Well, that was just an example off the top of my head. I had no knowledge of the document structure, and I was unaware of the wrapInner() method.